# Changing the language of Master Data Services

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

Yesterday, I installed and configured Master Data Services (after installing IIS and other required components). At no point during the installation did I get the option to pick a language (and if I did, I might have overlooked it).

When checking the web application, it seems to have defaulted to Danish language (possibly because that's the language Windows runs in?). Is there any way for me to change the language of Master Data Services anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: did you download sql server 2008 R2 service pack 1 / english version?

Comment: Hi, we're using SQL Server 2012. The installation is English, though the server collection was set to DANISH_NORWEGIAN. Not sure about any SPs being installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is certainly embarrassing.

`Control Panel` -> `Clock, Language, and Region` -> `Language`

Danish was shown on top. Select it, then click `Move down` so English is the default:

[image]

Restart Internet Explorer, point it t the MDS application and bob was my uncle:

[image]

Comment: These days Bob might be your aunt as well.

Comment: In Windows 10, this is now under `Language settings`